# Don't show older post in wordpress programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm using "The Future Is Now!" plugin and want to display all post that are schedule for the future. The only problem is, how do i make a query like (WHERE date >= $currentdate) before i enter the loop?

```
    <?php if (is_category('My awesome category')) {
        $currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
        /* Some sort of query with the statement date >= $currentdate? */
    }
    ?>

    /* The Loop */
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query_posts(array('post_status' => 'future'));
```

Edit: Above is the easy answer that fits with your loop, but as a default solution it's better that u use a new $WP_Query object:

```
$my_query = new $WP_Query;
$my_query->query_posts(array('post_status' => 'future'));

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();  // now the main wordpress query and post data is intact
```

2nd Edit: Similar query but with a filter:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the future
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '$now'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$q = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post'));
while ($q->have_posts()) : 
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile; 
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: The problem with the plugin in "The Future is now" it sets all future post to publish. So there is no post_status named future post, ever. So is it possible to make a query that checks the post_date and compares with with current date?